# Mandrill Transactional API/templates limit + offset parameters?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

Their API docs doesn't appear to contain any extra parameters for limit/offset (https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/templates/list-templates/).

Anyone had any luck using their API to query a large list of templates? I'm getting a 405 due to the number of templates...

I should be able to add limit/offset parameters to the query.